# Mysql Find if one column values are partially present in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql table which contains the subjects of emails. It has 2 columns, id and title. Some subjects might contain Re:, some might contain Fwd: and so on. I would like to write a query which returns rows where the value of the title of one row is contained in some other row. It is not necessarily an exact match but like finding a haystack in the needle. I have tried multiple ways like using sub queries or self join, but to no success. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result (as well formatted text.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: please share some sample data